# Unconditionally throw *this from constructor

Tags: c++, exception

I believe it's legal to throw *this from within the body of a constructor. I'd like to know if I'm simply wrong about this (issues passing around an object before it's constructor has completed?) or whether this is stylistically abhorrent.

I posted a second, more specific question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665036/is-an-object-fully-constructed-at-the-end-of-the-initialiser-list) which has been answered comprehensively. The code in this post is legal, if a little odd.

Given an exception struct:

```
struct fail final : public std::logic_error
{
  fail() : std::logic_error("fail") {}
  using std::logic_error::logic_error;
};
```

and a bunch of call sites like:

```
throw fail();
// or
throw fail("oh dear");
```

I am considering changing the struct to be:

```
struct fail final : public std::logic_error
{
  fail() : std::logic_error("fail") { throw * this; }
  fail(const char* w) : std::logic_error(w) { throw * this; }
};
```

At which point the call sites can remain unchanged, or be rewritten as the shorter:

```
fail();
// or
fail("oh dear");
```

This essentially means I no longer have to write throw all over the place. I can also continue catch the exception using the name "fail". It certainly seems to work, but leaves me with the suspicion that I may regret this choice later.

Thank you

edit: Thought slightly more about the behaviour.

1/ Throw *this is going to either make a copy of *this or move it if this counts as fair game for copy elision, so the destructor of logic_error firing isn't a problem

2/ The default copy constructor of a class with no members is probably just the copy constructor of the base so can probably copy *this

3/ The copy of *this that gets returned via the exception probably has undefined values for any members that are not set in the initialiser list

4/ Member functions can be called during construction. The (default) copy constructor is a member function so can be called during construction. throw *this will call the copy constructor. So I still believe the code is legal

Comment: What is so bad about writing `throw`? I cannot believe you go through all of this just to make the code harder to read.

Comment: The main issue that I see with this is that you're hiding the fact that you're throwing an exception from the people who read your code.

Comment: If you really want to avoid repeating `throw` over and over, consider wrapping your error-handling login into an *higher-order function* that contains **the entire throw/try/catch** error handling flow. Either abstract all of it away or none of it.

Comment: How is `throw *this` legal? Throwing an exception in a constructor cancels construction and auto-destructs any already-constructed members, so you would end up with a dead object. Or is the `throw` making a copy first?

Comment: @RemyLebeau My reasoning is that the base class is already constructed by this point and there's nothing more to do for the derived, but I don't wholly trust said reasoning

Comment: @JonChesterfield : If the derived class constructor throws the class is considered not constructed and the base class's destructor is called to clean up the mess. The catcher is catching a destroyed object.

Comment: @Unimportant I'm not sure about that. I think throw has probably made a copy first. I'm not sure if it's a copy of a complete object or not.

Comment: @JonChesterfield : Nothing will be copied before the object has been fully constructed, how can you copy something that according to the language rules does not even exist yet? The fact that the base class has been fully constructed matters not, you're creating a derived class object. (And even if it seems to work, that's just UB).

Comment: @Unimportant this hinges on exactly when an object is fully constructed. Is it after the base classes and initialiser list have been processed, or is it after than constructor has returned normally?

Comment: @JonChesterfield : After the constructor has returned normally, evidenced by the fact that if the constructor throws, an objects destructor will not be called, because it was never considered constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have sympathy with your desire to write expressive code.

This is the kind of thing I came up with for use in our code base, particularly when calling C APIs that return success or failure as an boolean-like integer.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>

struct failure : std::runtime_error
{
  using runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

template<class Message>
[[noreturn]]
bool fail(Message&& msg)
{
  throw failure(std::forward<Message>(msg));
}

int main()
{
  extern bool didSomething();

  didSomething() or fail("couldn't do it");
}
```

More fun with exceptions:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <system_error>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


namespace native
{
    struct no_message {};

    constexpr no_message join() { return {}; }

    template<class First, class...Rest>
    std::string join(First&& first, Rest&&...rest)
    {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << first;
        using expand = int[];
        void(expand{ 0,
                     ((ss << ' ' << rest),0)...
        });
        return ss.str();
    }

    [[noreturn]]
    void throwSystemError(no_message, int code)
    {
        throw std::system_error(code, std::system_category());
    }

    template<class Message>
    [[noreturn]]
    void throwSystemError(Message&& message, int code)
    {
        throw std::system_error(code, std::system_category(), message);
    }

    template<class...Parts>
    [[noreturn]]
    bool systemError(Parts&&...parts)
    {
        auto err = errno;
        throwSystemError(join(std::forward<Parts>(parts)...), err);
    }

    struct file_closer {
        void operator()(FILE* fp) const noexcept {
            std::fclose(fp);
        }
    };
    using FilePtr = std::unique_ptr<FILE, file_closer>;

    bool valid(FilePtr const& p) { return p.get(); }

    FilePtr openFile(const char* path, const char* mode)
    {
        auto ptr = FilePtr(std::fopen(path, mode));
        valid(ptr) or systemError("opening file", std::quoted(path), "in mode", std::quoted(mode));
        return ptr;
    }
}


int main()
try
{
    auto fptr = native::openFile("ibetthisdoesntexist.txt", "rb");
}
catch(std::system_error const& syserr)
{
    std::cerr << "system error: "
              << syserr.what()
              << ", error code " << syserr.code().value()
              << std::endl;
    std::exit(100);
}
```

example output:

```
system error: opening file "ibetthisdoesntexist.txt" in mode "rb": No such file or directory, error code 2
```

Comment: Do you actually use the ISO 646 alternate tokens? That seems like taking "expressive code" to the extreme, where you sacrifice writing idiomatic C++. As it is, I'm not sure that hiding a `throw` statement is doing any favors for readability.

Comment: I use ISO 646 all the time for boolean logic. Not only is it more readable, it's also impossible to write `&` when you meant to write `&&`. The `raise` call is useful for a few reasons. First, it defers the throw, so with very little refactoring I can insert (for example) logging or metrics at the throw site. The second is that I have an unhealthy affection for scripting languages like perl :)

Comment: Interesting. I like the use of fail for the verb and failure for the noun. This also disambiguates the code nicely. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The two disadvantages that I see:

- Not idiomatic, so it will surprise users that there is a hidden `throw`. So IMO, it is less readable.
- You cannot inherit from your class (as that base class throws) (you can mark the class `final` (from C++11) to highlight it).

Comment: I broadly agree on non-idiomatic. It looked strange enough to motivate this question after all. The inheritance limitation is a great observation, I've marked the struct as final (on the experimental branch and in the question), thanks